# What are the benefits of adopting multi-dimensional model (cube) given all these compute power and storage are available in the cloud?

Tags: ssas

We know that over a decade ago with very limited compute power and storage available, the invention of multi-dimensional model (cube) was to solve the above problem, e.g.SSAS. However with recent cloud technology advancement, compute power and storage are cheap, I struggle to see the point of using multi-dimensional model (cube,) in a enterprise business analytic solution?

Anyone has any other thoughts to share please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Per my opinion the greatest advantage of having SSAS model in an enterprise business analytic solution is that the end user can connect to it through Excel and just drag and drop measures and dimensions and create all kinds of useful reports with all kinds of calculations that are built in the cube (year to date, rolling 12, etc...), and without this model, they will have to rely on relational database to create much of complicated SQL calculations on their own, and first of all they will have to know SQL in details to do this, so they will probably have to rely on some kind of IT stuff to help them on daily basis to do this.
In SSAS, besides multidimensional there is also a tabular model, but the answer would be the same.